# Seeking a data structure for distributed counting in C++ for Frequency Cap implementation

Tags: c++, redis, counter, distributed-computing

I'm currently working on a project that involves implementing a frequency cap for user actions, and I'm facing some performance issues with my current solution. I would greatly appreciate your expertise and suggestions on how to optimize it. Here's an excerpt of my current code:

```
auto keyName = "cap:user_id";

increment.push_back(Redis::Command(
    "INCR",
    keyName
));
increment.push_back(Redis::Command(
    "EXPIRE",
    keyName,
    "86400",
    "NX"
));

Redis::Results results = redis.execMulti(increment);
```

Then, before every action, I perform a Redis GET on the key and check how many times that user ID performed the action. To provide a bit of context, I'm using C++ for this project, and I initially chose Redis for managing the distributed counter since it's a reliable tool. However, I've observed that the performance is not meeting the desired standards for our frequency cap code. Specifically, the counter updates are slower than expected, but also the GETs.

Given the constraints, I'm exploring alternative in-memory data structures that might offer better performance for maintaining a distributed counter. Or maybe is there a service faster than Redis for this type of thing?  The goal is to efficiently count how many times a specific user ID performs a particular action. My current code runs in 2 threads, but could be more.

Comment: What Redis C++ library are you using? I can't find `execMulti` in neither [redis-plus-plus](https://github.com/sewenew/redis-plus-plus) nor [Boost.Redis](https://github.com/boostorg/redis)

Comment: Fwiw, I think you may want to look into the [pipelining](https://redis.io/docs/manual/pipelining/) in [Boost.Redis](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/redis/doc/html/index.html) if that's not what's being used by `execMulti`.

Comment: "Then, before every action, I perform a Redis GET on the key and check how many times that user ID performed the action."

Sounds like you are playing ping-pong with the cache. Use [functions](https://redis.io/docs/interact/programmability/functions-intro/) to model more complex transactions so that stuff like "check + increment" can be done server side in a single roundtrip.

Comment: I'm using hiredis. Should I use something else?

Comment: _"hiredis_" - Ok, so you built your own C++ library on top of hiredis? That's fine, I was just curious about where `execMulti` came from. The redis-plus-plus C++ library is also built on top of hiredis. Boost.Redis (available since boost 1.84) is not - and if one wants to believe what Boost.Redis is saying, it supports pipelining in a better way than redis-plus-plus. Using functions as Ext3h mentioned also sounds interesting.

Answer (score 1):

Since your work is in the *read (GET frequency), compute (if not reaching the limit, increment it), write (update the counter and set expiration)* pattern, you should use [Lua scripting](https://redis.io/commands/eval) to avoid RTT (Round Trip Time).

```
string script = R"(
local key = KEYS[1]
local limit = ARGV[1]
local cnt = redis.call('get', key)
if cnt ~= nil and cnt == limit then
    -- reach the limit
    return -1
else
    local res = redis.call('incr', key)
    redis.call('expire', key, '86400', 'NX')
end
)"

// If you use redis-plus-plus:
auto r = Redis("redis://127.0.0.1");   // You should reuse Redis object for each `eval` operation.
string key = "counter";
string limit = to_string(10);

auto res = r.eval<long long>(script, {key}, {limit});
```

Disclamer: I'm the author of redis-plus-plus

Comment: Please do not recommend the use of `eval` - functions should be *always* be loaded eagerly.

Comment: At least when targeting Redis 7.0 and higher. Ephemeral scripts have outlived their usefulness. Even though it looks like redis-plus-plus is yet missing this feature / command? https://github.com/sewenew/redis-plus-plus/issues/514

Comment: Is there a way to issue a Redis GET and get a response in less than 5 ms? Mine keeps hitting 10 ms, 15 ms.

Comment: @vinnylinux easily. Check https://redis.io/docs/management/optimization/latency/ if you fell for any of the usual traps.

Comment: @Ext3h Yes, function support is still on the way. However, you can always use the [generic interface](https://github.com/sewenew/redis-plus-plus#generic-command-interface) to send function related commands to Redis.